# Git SYNC issue - Not able to perform Sync due to error - Not duplicate questions

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have updated my Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.10.3.
Since then I am not able perform any Operation (SYNC,PULL,FETCH etc..)

There are no lock files inside git folder

[image]

And also I tried checking any other lock files inside my repo - I did not find any local files

[image]

> Unable to create '/.git/index.lock': File exists.
> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
> an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
> are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
> may have crashed in this repository earlier:
> remove the file manually to continue.
> Updating 7923482d..d7a50bfb
> Pull operation failed.

I have tried following things:

1. Deleted index file (this is not a lock file) - still no lock

Comment: The `find` command you’re trying to run is a Unix command, it doesn’t work like in the Windows command line. You’ll need to use a different command.

Comment: I checked - I don't see any lock files, please suggest me on this error